# Aggregate information from multiple contacts into an account

Tags: account, contact, aggregate

is it possible to create a custom object which will take information from all contacts under an account and aggregate information into that account record? Here's what i'm trying to do specifically...

I want to take the lead scores of all contacts in an account and combine their scores into one large score for that account.

Is that possible?

Comment: Sounds like a regular roll-up summary field. Have you tried that, assuming your score is numeric?

Comment: the score is numeric and I have not tried the roll-up summary. thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can't rollup from Contact to Account.  A common pain, and ridiculous that its not available

Answer (score 1):

This could be done either by a trigger or a batch job, depending on if you need to the account information to be updated in real time or if its something that could be daily, weekly, etc.

I would likely create a batch job for this, and then shcedule it to run whenever you want.  Heres a sample I made from some batch jobs I have

```
global class myBatchJob implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{

    global final string query;

    global myBatchJob(){
        query = 'Select Id, Name, AccountLeadScore__c, (Select Id, Name, ContactLeadScore__c From Contacts) From Account';      
    } 

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC,List<sObject> scope)
    {
        List<Account> updateAccounts = new List<Account>();

        for(Sobject s : scope){
            Account a = (Account) s;
            a.AccountLeadScore = 0;
            for(Contact c : a.Contacts){
                a.AccountLeadScore__c += c.ContactLeadScore__c
            }
            updateAccounts.add(a);
        }  

        try{
            update updateAccounts;
        }catch (Exception e) {  
            //your trapping
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.WARN,'Batch Job complete');
    }

}
```

Comment: Glad to help out

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will be able to score contacts(aggregated) and accounts with '**ZakScorer**'. You can find this app on appexchange and try it for yourself.

To install ZakScorer, [click here...](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B5O0FEAV)